# Replacement for Linux Standard Base?

Tags: linux, binary-compatibility, lsb

When distributing source code **is not an option** the Linux Standard Base allows a mechanism for achieving binary compatibility with many Linux distros.

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb

However, it appears that it has been somewhat abandoned as an approach:

https://github.com/LinuxStandardBase/lsb/blob/master/README.md

I'd be interested in thoughts on the best path forward for maintaining binary compatibility. The document referenced above basically says "Linux is evolving so rapidly that it's not practical to have a standard base". I can appreciate that, but what are the other options? It's difficult to google this topic because you mostly get references about the LSB.

Comment: The canonical solution is to **develop free software** and publish its source code. Then the burden of porting it to distributions is on the distribution makers. You could help them for widely used package management (e.g. by packaging your free software to `.deb`). In other words, Linux (& POSIX) is more about *source compatibility* than binary compatibility.

Comment: Editing question to reflect source distribution is not an option.

Comment: Then you are on your own, and you might not get any help here, since it is off-topic (you are not showing any source code or command). You might sometimes try static linking (but remember that libc is often LGPL licensed, so you need to enable relinking to a newer libc)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development...seems on topic to me.

Comment: It could be the case that keeping the source code proprietary would cost more to your company or client than publish it as free software, precisely because of such packaging and system incompatibilities issues.

Comment: You don't have to convince me...but I don't make those decisions.

Comment: You might look into [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)